# HashMap: Find next lower key

Tags: java, hashmap

I am currently storing marshalling libraries for different client versions in a HashMap.
The libs are loaded using the `org.reflections` API. For simplicity sake I'll just insert a few values here by hand. They are unordered by intent, because I have no influence on in which order the map is initialized on start-up by the reflections API.
The keys (ClientVersion) are enums.

```
HashMap<ClientVersion, IMarshalLib> MAP = new HashMap<>();
MAP.put(ClientVersion.V100, new MarshalLib100());
MAP.put(ClientVersion.V110, new MarshalLib110());
MAP.put(ClientVersion.V102, new MarshalLib102());
MAP.put(ClientVersion.V101, new MarshalLib101());
MAP.put(ClientVersion.V150, new MarshalLib150());
```

All and well so far, the problem now is, that there are client versions out there where the marshalling did not change since the previous version.

Let's say, we have a client version `ClientVersion.V140`. In this particular case I am looking for `MarshalLib110`, assigned to ClientVersion.V110.

How would I get the desired result (without iterating through all entries and grabbing "the next lower" value each time)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. Use a TreeMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I get the desired result (without iterating through all entries and grabbing "the next lower" value each time)

There is nothing you can do about "iterating through all entries" part: since the map is unordered, there is no way of finding the next smaller item without iterating the entire set of keys.

However, there is something you can do about the "each time" part: if you make a copy of this map into a `TreeMap`, you would be able to look up the next smaller item by calling the [`floorEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry%28K%29) method.

Another alternative is to copy the keys into an array on the side, sort the array, and run a binary search each time that you need to look up the next smaller key. With the key in hand, you can look up the entry in your hash map.

Comment: The `TreeMap` totally did the trick! Great, thanks very much! Although the method I needed was `floorEntry()` rather than `ceilingEntry()`.

Comment: Note: the method ceilingKey(..) "returns the least key greater than or equal to the given key": ceilingKey(102) returns 102.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use NavigableSet. Look at this example:

```
    HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(100, "MarshalLib100");
    map.put(110, "MarshalLib110");
    map.put(102, "MarshalLib102");
    map.put(101, "MarshalLib101");
    map.put(150, "MarshalLib150");

    NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());

    Integer key = set.lower(150);   // ^ -> 110
    String  val = map.get(key);     // ^ -> MarshalLib110

    // or
    key = set.higher(110);// ^ -> 150
    val = map.get(key);   // ^ -> MarshalLib150
```

**Update**: Using TreeMap to ***find next lower key*** is not really correct. Example:

```
    TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    treeMap.put(100, "MarshalLib100");
    treeMap.put(110, "MarshalLib110");
    treeMap.put(102, "MarshalLib102");
    treeMap.put(101, "MarshalLib101");
    treeMap.put(150, "MarshalLib150");

    System.out.println(treeMap.floorKey(102));
    System.out.println(treeMap.floorEntry(102)); 
    System.out.println(treeMap.ceilingKey(102));
    System.out.println(treeMap.ceilingEntry(102));
```

**Output:**

```
102
102=MarshalLib102
102
102=MarshalLib102
```

Comment: This seems to get rather complicated, because I'm not using raw integers as my version numbers, but Version enums.

Comment: It does not matter since your key class implements Comparable interface.

Comment: Four your update: This is exactly the behaviour I need for this. `floorEntry()` returns the **exact** value if it can find it, OR the next lower one if not. From the docs: _Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key._

Comment: From your Question: "Let's say, we have a client version ClientVersion.V140. In this particular case I am looking for MarshalLib110, assigned to ClientVersion.V110.".